# Lost syntax highlighting in Textmate

Tags: syntax-highlighting, textmate

Using Textmate, I have somehow managed to turn off syntax highlighting for php files. After much trial and error, I have worked out that this happened when I accidentally hit SHIFT-CTRL-OPTION-D (I'm on a Mac, btw). I've looked everywhere and tried many key combinations, but I cannot figure out how to re-enable the nice syntax highlighting. Please help me, Textmate gurus, you're my only hope!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key sequence SHIFT-CTRL-OPTION-D corresponds to an option in the language menu down at the bottom left of the Textmate window. The language menu tells Textmate what language to consider the file so it can determine the proper syntax highlighting. The key sequence I hit caused Textmate to highlight my text as though it were a diff window. Switched it back to PHP and it works great now.

Comment: the other answer from @xfactorial gives the explanation why this key combination did the trick!

Comment: for those that don't -want- syntax highlighting, let me recommend the SHIFT-CTRL-OPTION-P sequence, then select plain text. it leaves your display largely undecorated.

Answer (score 8):

I don't have enough rep to add a comment, so I'll expand on the accepted answer here.

`SHIFT+CONTROL+OPTION+<LETTER>` will display a menu showing all grammars beginning with `<LETTER>`.  So if you want PHP back, just hit `SHIFT+CONTRL+OPTION+P`, and then a list of languages beginning with 'P' will pop up.  You can choose one from the list by pressing the corresponding number (on my computer, it's `2`).